# php ldap_search in Active Directory root DN - empty results

Tags: php, linux, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to query Active directory for a given user group membership.
When I search a specific user's OU, the search works ok.
When I try to search the entire directory, the result is empty.
Since I have many user OU's, and specific user OU may vary.

The system is CentOS 6.4 with PHP+Apache.

Here is the code:

```
$ldap_dn = "dc=ccc,dc=bbb,dc=aaa,dc=com";

// Active Directory user for querying
$query_user = "ldap_bind@ccc.bbb.aaa.com";
$password = "xxxx";

// Connect to AD
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host, 389) or die("Could not connect to LDAP");
ldap_bind($ldap,$query_user,$password) or die("Could not bind to LDAP");
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

// Search AD
$results = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,"(sAMAccountName=$user)",array("memberof","primarygroupid"));
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);
if($entries['count'] == 0) {
    echo "No results\n";
    return false;
}
```

Have anyone ever seen similar results? am I missing something or any configuration to support such search?

Answer (score 4):

The correct code iss...

```
$ldap_dn = "dc=ccc,dc=bbb,dc=aaa,dc=com";

// Active Directory user for querying
$query_user = "ldap_bind@ccc.bbb.aaa.com";
$password = "xxxx";

// Connect to AD
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host, 389) or die("Could not connect to LDAP");

->>> bfore ldap_bind<<<- ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
->>> bfore ldap_bind<<<- ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

ldap_bind($ldap,$query_user,$password) or die("Could not bind to LDAP");


// Search AD
$results = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,"(sAMAccountName=$user)",array("memberof","primarygroupid"));
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);
if($entries['count'] == 0) {
    echo "No results\n";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The key is calling ldap_set_option() **between** ldap_connect() and ldap_bind(). Thank you.